# Windows 11 Poetry EnvCommandError

Tags: python-poetry

When I run `Poetry Install`, I get the following error.

> Creating virtualenv s in C:\Users\M\Desktop\Projects\S.venv
>
> EnvCommandError
>
> Command "C:\Users\M\Desktop\Projects.venv\Scripts\python.exe" -W ignore -
> errored with the following return code 101, and output:    Unable to
> create process using 'C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -W ignore -'
> input was : import sys
> if hasattr(sys, "real_prefix"):
> print(sys.real_prefix)   elif hasattr(sys, "base_prefix"):
> print(sys.base_prefix)   else:
> print(sys.prefix)
>
> at ~.poetry\lib\poetry\utils\env.py:1195 in *run
> 1191│                 output = subprocess.check_output(
> 1192│                     cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, **kwargs
> 1193│                 )
> 1194│         except CalledProcessError as e:
> → 1195│             raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input*)
> 1196│
> 1197│         return decode(output)
> 1198│
> 1199│     def execute(self, bin, *args, **kwargs):